# Ceph does not detect disks

Tags: ceph

I am using cephadm. I had a test cluster up and running. I re-installed the OS and during installation nuked the drives by deleting the LVM volume groups and partitions. Now `lsblk` shows the devices to be present but `ceph orch device ls` returns nothing. I had thought that the problem was residual partition tables or LVM data so I have tried the following:

- `cephadm ceph-volume lvm zap --destroy /dev/sda` => error: argument DEVICES: invalid
- `ceph orch device zap host1 /dev/sdc --force` => Error EINVAL: Device path '/dev/sda' not found on host 'host1'
- `wipefs -fa /dev/sda`
- `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda bs=1M count=1024`
- `sgdisk --zap-all /dev/sda`

None of these worked. Any suggestions? Any help much appreciated.

Comment: What is the output of `lsblk` on host1?

Comment: As I said, `lsblk` shows the drives to be present. I can even mount them after `mkfs.ext /dev/sda`. There is nothing wrong with the drives themselves.

Answer (score 2):

I'm experiencing the same issue with some disks that have data written on them. When I run the lsblk command, the disk shows multiple partitions:

```
sda 8:0 0 7.3T 0 disk
├─sda1 8:1 0 1.9T 0 part
└─sda2 8:2 0 1.9T 0 part
```

I've tried several wipe commands:

```
wipefs -a /dev/sda --force
shred -n 1 -s -v /dev/sda
```

However, none of them worked when I wanted to zap my disk. I found a solution to fix this! I reformatted the disk with **fdisk** to an empty gpt partition:

```
fdisk /dev/sda
```

1. Remove all partitions with `d`
2. Create a new empty gpt partition with `g`
3. Save the changes with `w`

After saving, Ceph immediately recognized the disk.

Then I can zap the disk using the following command: `ceph orch device zap <hostname> /dev/sda --force`

Answer (score 0):

I solved this in the end with `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda bs=1M` and after a few hours the drive became available to Ceph. Presumably there is some data structure written further into the drive.

Comment: I have the same problem, `dd` does not solve the issue :(